# Изменение цвета текста

Tags: jquery, вёрстка, css

Каким образом можно сверстать текст с переходом цвета, например, буквы вверху зеленые, а к низу цвет плавно переходит в желтый? Подозреваю, на css такого не добиться и нужно использовать javascript/jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужно [что-то в этом роде](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/BXvBF/), то есть [плагины](http://mrnix.ru/pxgradient/index_en.html) (напр. [этот](http://www.codefocus.ca/goodies/gradienttext) использовал в примере). Какой лучше или хуже - не сравнивал, но попробуйте забить в поиск как-нибудь так: "[text gradient jquery](https://www.google.com/search?q=text%20gradient%20jquery)"

Comment: @Deonis спасибо!